# Pure CSS responsive flipping boxes

Tags: html, css

I want to have some flipping boxes. On mouse over, the image flips and shows the text. 
This works, but its not responsive (the 2nd row boxes ends over the previous row).
The problem is .f_contenedor height, but I want this to be responsive, so I'm using the "padding-top: 56%" property.

How can I make sure "f_contendor" height is the same as .face?

There is an example here http://bregna.org/flip.html

and this is the snippet. Is the same code, just the backgrounds are different.

```css
        .f_contenedor:hover .f_card {
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
            box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
        }

        .f_contenedor {
            position: relative;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 50%;
            height: auto;
            z-index: 1;
            float: left;
            perspective: 1000;
            box-sizing:border-box;;
        }

        .f_card {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transition: all .3s linear;

        }

        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            .f_contenedor {
                width: 50%;
            }
        }

        @media (min-width: 992px) {
            .f_contenedor {
                width: 30%;
            }

        }

        .shadow {
            -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.6);
            -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.6);
            box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.6);
        }

        .face {
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        .face {
            position: absolute;

            width: 100%;
            height: 0;
            padding-top: 56%;
            backface-visibility: hidden;

        }

        .face.back {
            display: block;
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
            box-sizing: border-box;
            height: 100%;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #aaa;
        }

        .face.back span {
            margin-top: -56%;
            padding: 12px;
            display: block;
        }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es_MX">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"/>
    <title>Flip</title>
    
</head>
<body>
<div class="f_contenedor">
    <div class="f_card" style="background-color: black">
        <div class="back face text-center shadow">
            <span>
                <h1>WEB</h1>
                <p>Accusantium delectus non quae. Aliquam delectus, dolorem ea id, inventore libero molestias numquam, porro quasi quibusdam reiciendis sequi soluta tenetur veniam voluptatem.
                </p></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="f_contenedor">
    <div class="f_card">
        <div class="front face shadow" style="background-color: orange">
        </div>
        <div class="back face text-center shadow">
            <span>
                <h1>CMS</h1>
                <p>Accusantium delectus non quae. Aliquam delectus, dolorem ea id, inventore libero molestias numquam, porro quasi quibusdam reiciendis sequi.
                </p></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="f_contenedor">
    <div class="f_card">
        <div class="front face shadow" style="background-color : firebrick;">
        </div>
        <div class="back face text-center shadow">
            <span>
                <h1>THE GRID</h1>
                <p>Accusantium delectus non quae. Aliquam delectus, dolorem ea id, inventore libero molestias numquam.
                </p></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="f_contenedor">
    <div class="f_card">
        <div class="front face shadow" style="background-color: green">
        </div>
        <div class="back face text-center shadow">
            <span>
                <h1>FLOWERS</h1>
                <p>Ad, aperiam blanditiis dolorem dolorum ea earum ipsam laboriosam molestias non odio provident .
                </p></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="f_contenedor">
    <div class="f_card">
        <div class="front face shadow" style="background-color: yellow">
        </div>
        <div class="back face text-center shadow">
            <span>
                <h1>DRINKS</h1>
                <p>Accusamus animi earum enim ex impedit nesciunt nihil quod quos vel? Dolores fugit harum modi placeat quasi  quam?
                </p></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="f_contenedor">
    <div class="f_card">
        <div class="front face shadow" style="background-color: greenyellow">
        </div>
        <div class="back face text-center shadow">
            <span>
                <h1>MURALS</h1>
                <p>Aperiam aut consequuntur nostrum rem similique temporibus veritatis.
                </p></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could slightly adjust your CSS so that the `.back` face is exclusively positioned with absolute, and aligned to the top of the parent. Additionally, you would want to adjust the `.face` to be relatively positioned.

So something along these lines:

```
.face {
  /*   position: absolute; Remove this */ 
  position:relative; /* Position the face relatively by default */

  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;

}

.face.back {
  position:absolute; /* For back faces, these should be positioned with absolute */
  top:0; /* Align back faces with the top of the parent */
  display: block;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

Comment: what version of IE are you targeting?

Comment: IE 11. I noticed that `transform-style: preserve-3d` doesn't support in IE.